# HttpUrlConnection post request issue

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection

i have issue with post request. Server gets me response message ok, but doesn't recognize json what i send as post body. I have tried almost everything. Php attribute $_POST is always empty.
Thank for your answers.

Json has structure :

```
{
  "data": {
       "email": "something@something.com",
       "password": "tralala"
   }
}
```

Android code :

```
public static Pair<Integer, String> signUpByEmailPost(String username, String passwd) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL + "create/createUser.php");
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConn.connect();

        JSONObject json = createJsonCredentials(username, passwd);
        String dataString = json.toString();
        Log.i(TAG, dataString);

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream());
        out.write(dataString);
        out.flush();

        int httpResult = resolveHttpResponseCode(urlConn);
        if(httpResult > 0) {
            return new Pair<>(httpResult, null);
        }

        String receivedDataString = getStringContentFromConnection(urlConn);
        return new Pair<>(0, receivedDataString);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new Pair<>(3, null);
}

private static JSONObject createJsonCredentials(String username, String password) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonInner = new JSONObject();
        jsonInner.put("email", "something@something.com");
        jsonInner.put("password", "tralala");

        JSONObject jsonOuter = new JSONObject();
        jsonOuter.put("data", jsonInner);

        return jsonOuter;
    } catch(JSONException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Server response :

```
{
    success: false,
    errors: {
        email: "blank_email",
        password: "blank_password"
    }
}
```

Server side :

```
<?php
    $data["post"] = $_POST;
    $email = $_POST["data"]["email"];
    $password = $_POST["data"]["password"];

    if(empty($email)) {
        $errors['email'] = 'blank_email';
    }
    if(empty($password)) {
        $errors['password'] = 'blank_password';
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: is your createJSONCredentials throwing any exception?

Comment: I recommend using a REST client to save yourself a whole lot of time. [Retrofit](http://github.com/square/retrofit) would be a great choice.

Comment: No exception. Everything seem's alright, but json is not recognized on server. I compared my json with iOS colleague's one and they are equals. But his request works. I will give retrofit a shot.

Comment: `"Content-Type", "application/json"`. Indeed then at php your POST array will be empty. Use php://input and json_decode() instead. Google for them.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here you are returning null value from your method. Try this code. It will work.

```
private static JSONObject createJsonCredentials(String username, String password) {

        JSONObject jsonOuter = new JSONObject();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonInner = new JSONObject();
            jsonInner.put("email", "something@something.com");
            jsonInner.put("password", "tralala");


            jsonOuter.put("data", jsonInner);


        } catch(JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonOuter;
    }
```